# Ranking within multiple groups & Efficient query for multiple table updates

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to add rank by sales by month and also change the date column to a 'month end' field that would show only last day of month.

Can i do two sets in a row like that without adding an update?
I'm looking for top 2 within each month -  does limit and group by work?
I feel like this is right and most efficient query, but its not working - any help appreciated!!

```
        UPDATE table1
        SET DATE=EOMONTH(DATE) AS MONTH_END;       
        ALTER TABLE table1
        ADD COLUMN RANK INT AFTER sales;
        UPDATE table1
        SET RANK=
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY cust ORDER BY sales DESC);
        LIMIT 2
```

orig table

```
    +------+----------+-------+--+
    | CUST |   DATE   | SALES |  |
    +------+----------+-------+--+
    |   36 | 3-5-2018 |    50 |  |
    |   37 | 3-15-18  |   100 |  |
    |   38 | 3-25-18  |    65 |  |
    |   37 | 4-5-18   |    95 |  |
    |   39 | 4-21-18  |   500 |  |
    |   40 | 4-45-18  |   199 |  |
    +------+----------+-------+--+
desired output

+------+-----------+-------+------+
| CUST | Month End | SALES | Rank |
+------+-----------+-------+------+
|      |           |       |      |
|   37 | 3-31-18   |   100 |    1 |
|   38 | 3-31-18   |    65 |    2 |
|   39 | 4-30-18   |   500 |    1 |
|   40 | 4-30-18   |   199 |    2 |
+------+-----------+-------+------+
```

Comment: *"getting error"*? It seems you forgot to tell us what that error is. Please do include that in your question (not as a comment).

Comment: can you point to the semicolon?  Not sure what you're talking about. Im trying to figure out how to show top 2 within each month - that's why I posted the question - trying group by but yes it isn't working looking for suggestions

Comment: `sales DESC);
        LIMIT 2 `

Comment: if i do that then the top two are both in april.  I need top two within each month -march and april

Comment: near duplicate of question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53367587 so it looks like homework.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why you want EOMONTH as a stored value, but what you have for that will work.

I would not use [rank] as a column name as I avoid any words that are used in SQL, maybe [sales_rank] or similar.

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ADD COLUMN [sales_rank] INT AFTER sales;

with cte as (
    select
          cust
        , DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY cust ORDER BY sales DESC) as ranking
    from table1
    )
update cte
set sales_rank = ranking
where ranking < 3
;
```

LIMIT 2 is not something that can be used in SQL Server by the way, and it sure can't be used "per grouping". When you use a "window function" such as `rank()` or `dense_rank()` you can use the output of those in the where clause of the next "layer". i.e. use those functions in a subquery (or cte) and then use a where clause to filter rows by the calculated values.

Also note I used `dense_rank()` to guarantee that no rank numbers are skipped, so that the subsequent where clause will be effective.