# Rank by top customers within each separate month -

Tags: sql-server

I am having trouble ranking top customers by month.  I created a new Rank column - but how do I break it up by month?  Any help plz.  Code and tables below:

The logic for ranking is selecting the top two customers per month from the tables.  Also wrapped  into the code (attempted at least) is renaming the date field and setting it to reflect end of month date only.

```
 SELECT * FROM table1;
UPDATE table1
SET DATE=EOMONTH(DATE) AS MO_END;
ALTER TABLE table1
ADD COLUMN RANK INT AFTER SALES;
UPDATE table1
SET RANK=
RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY cust ORDER BY sales DESC);
LIMIT 2
```

Starting wtih

```
------+----------+-------+--+
| CUST |   DATE   | SALES |  |
+------+----------+-------+--+
|   36 | 3-5-2018 |    50 |  |
|   37 | 3-15-18  |   100 |  |
|   38 | 3-25-18  |    65 |  |
|   37 | 4-5-18   |    95 |  |
|   39 | 4-21-18  |   500 |  |
|   40 | 4-45-18  |   199 |  |
+------+----------+-------+--+
```

desired end result

```
+------+---------+-------+------+--+
| CUST | MO_END  | SALES | RANK |  |
+------+---------+-------+------+--+
|   37 | 3-31-18 |   100 |    1 |  |
|   38 | 3-25-18 |    65 |    2 |  |
|   39 | 4-30-18 |   500 |    1 |  |
|   40 | 4-45-18 |   199 |    2 |  |
+------+---------+-------+------+--+
```

Comment: can you explain the logic for ranking that you want ?

Comment: sure thanks i added it into the description above

Comment: near duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53364224 so it appears to be homework

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ranking within multiple groups & Efficient query for multiple table updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53364224/ranking-within-multiple-groups-efficient-query-for-multiple-table-updates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a simple selection:

```
select * 
from   (
    select
          table1.*
        , DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY cust, EOMONTH(DATE) ORDER BY sales DESC) as ranking
    from table1
    )
where ranking < 3
;
```

---

If storing is important: I would not use [rank] as a column name as I avoid any words that are used in SQL, maybe [sales_rank] or similar.

```
with cte as (
    select
          cust
        , DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY cust, EOMONTH(DATE) ORDER BY sales DESC) as ranking
    from table1
    )
update cte
set sales_rank = ranking
where ranking < 3
;
```

There is really no reason to store the end of month, just use that function within the partition of the `over()` clause.

LIMIT 2 is not something that can be used in SQL Server by the way, and it sure can't be used "per grouping". When you use a "window function" such as `rank()` or `dense_rank()` you can use the output of those in the where clause of the next "layer". i.e. use those functions in a subquery (or cte) and then use a where clause to filter rows by the calculated values.

Also note I used `dense_rank()` to guarantee that no rank numbers are skipped, so that the subsequent where clause will be effective.

Comment: thanks so much. I have a couple questions.. 1)In the dense rank expression, are you naming that ranking with 'as ranking'  - sales_rank or any kind of rank column didn't exist in orig table.  2)when you say 'with cte' or update cte' are you saying common table expression im guess?  can't i just start off the query with select*table1 cust, dense_rank...etc and then update table1 for the next layer.  thank you for the explanation its really helpful

Comment: 1, AS is not part of the alias, so NO. 2. Yes, you don't have to store these values, so you could just have a select query. I added to the answer.